# Save Data From Recordset to XML With VB 6.0

Tags: xml, vb6

```
Dim Rs As New `Adodb.Recordset`
Rs.Open "select * from Customer ",Conn,adOpenDynamic,adLockOptimistic
if Rs.RecordCount > 0 then
    rs.Save App.Path & "\Customer.xml" , adPersistXML
end if
```

The Problem is when record is null then the data is not stored in `xml`.

So how to make all the stored data into `xml` data including null.

Answer (score 0):

if u can show us XML structure it will be more helpful. you cannot store null directly in XML. But you have two option

- Either a missing tag which will be considered as null
- Make attribute nillable = true

---

Answer (score 0):

You can't force a Null value to export as XML that way.  The ADO rowset schema is designed to "omit" them intentionally.

You also didn't give a specific schema to create, but you can easily mimic the ADO schema if you wanted to.

The best way is to take control of the process yourself.  Here is a SAX example though I didn't bother to imitate the ADO schema here:

```
Option Explicit
'
'Requires references to:
'
'   Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects, version 2.5 or later.
'   Microsoft XML 6.0, can be rewritten to use 3.0 as well.
'

Private Enum HRESULT
    S_OK = 0
End Enum

Private Enum STGM
    STGM_READ = &H0&
    STGM_WRITE = &H1&
    STGM_READWRITE = &H2&
    STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE = &H10&
    STGM_SHARE_DENY_WRITE = &H20&
    STGM_SHARE_DENY_READ = &H30&
    STGM_SHARE_DENY_NONE = &H40&
    STGM_FAILIFTHERE = &H0&
    STGM_CREATE = &H1000&
End Enum

Private Declare Function SHCreateStreamOnFile Lib "shlwapi" _
    Alias "SHCreateStreamOnFileW" ( _
    ByVal pszFile As Long, _
    ByVal grfMode As STGM, _
    ByRef stm As IUnknown) As HRESULT

Private Sub CustomSaveXML( _
    ByVal Recordset As ADODB.Recordset, _
    ByVal FilePath As String)
    Dim Stream As IUnknown
    Dim HRESULT As HRESULT
    Dim Attributes As SAXAttributes60
    Dim Writer As MSXML2.MXXMLWriter60
    Dim Handler As MSXML2.IVBSAXContentHandler
    Dim Field As ADODB.Field
    Dim StringValue As String

    Set Stream = Nothing 'Force creation on 64-bit Windows.  Not sure why
                         'this is required or why it works.
    HRESULT = SHCreateStreamOnFile(StrPtr(FilePath), _
                                   STGM_CREATE _
                                Or STGM_WRITE _
                                Or STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE, _
                                   Stream)
    If HRESULT <> S_OK Then
        Err.Raise &H80044900, _
                  "CustomSaveXML", _
                  "SHCreateStreamOnFile error " & Hex$(HRESULT)
    End If
    Set Attributes = New MSXML2.SAXAttributes60
    Set Writer = New MSXML2.MXXMLWriter60
    Set Handler = Writer
    With Writer
        .omitXMLDeclaration = True
        .standalone = True
        .disableOutputEscaping = False
        .indent = True
        .encoding = "utf-8"
        .output = Stream
    End With
    With Handler
        .startDocument
        .startElement "", "", "data", Attributes
        Do Until Recordset.EOF
            With Attributes
                For Each Field In Recordset.Fields
                    Select Case VarType(Field.Value)
                        Case vbNull
                            'Force as empty String:
                            StringValue = ""
                        Case vbString
                            StringValue = Field.Value
                        Case Else
                            'This converts to a String value using the
                            'Invariant Locale:
                            StringValue = LTrim$(Str$(Field.Value))
                    End Select
                    .addAttribute "", "", Field.Name, "", StringValue
                Next
            End With
            .startElement "", "", "row", Attributes
            .endElement "", "", "row"
            Attributes.Clear
            Recordset.MoveNext
        Loop
        .endElement "", "", "data"
        .endDocument
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Main()
    Dim RS As ADODB.Recordset

    With New ADODB.Connection
        .Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='.';" _
              & "Extended Properties='Text;CSVDelimited=True;Hdr=True'"
        Set RS = .Execute("sample.csv", , adCmdTableDirect)
        CustomSaveXML RS, "sample2.xml"
        RS.Close
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

Input data:

```
LongVal,StringVal,DoubleVal
65536,Fred,3.5
,Has-Null,1.23456
65537,Barney,37
```

Output XML:

```
<data>
    <row LongVal="65536" StringVal="Fred" DoubleVal="3.5"/>
    <row LongVal="" StringVal="Has-Null" DoubleVal="1.23456"/>
    <row LongVal="65537" StringVal="Barney" DoubleVal="37"/>
</data>
```

You could also brute-force things and just write it as a file using conventional logic and the intrinsic VB6 I/O statements.  It just gets a little tricker if you need true UTF-8 output or something, or your XML schema is more complex.

Comment: Sir Bob77.. 
Do you have Email..??

Comment: We're not currently taking job applications.